# Short Interest for CBOE

Tags: short-selling

Does anyone know why websites (yahoo finance, morningstar etc) do not show short-interest for CBOE after Sept 14th 2018?

Comment: They changed their primary exchange.  https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/cboe-global-markets-transfers-common-stock-listing-exclusively-to-cboe-300714613.html

Comment: Thank you. It appears none of the big websites (morningstar, wsj, yahoo finance etc) will report their SI number. Only available from the cboe website now.